# typeof(interface).IsAssignableFrom(intptr) returns true

Tags: c#

I need to go through all the properties that implement an interface, and i have an IntPtr property that passes the IsAssignableFrom condotion.

Is there any other way to check if a property implements the interface?

This is the method that goes through the properties:

```
protected void SetOwner()
{
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> sourceProperties = this.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in sourceProperties)
    {
        if (pi.Name != "Owner" && pi.DeclaringType.GetInterface("IOwnerSystem") != null)
        //i tried this too: typeof(IOwnerSystem).IsAssignableFrom(pi.DeclaringType))
        {
            IOwnerSystem systm = (IOwnerSystem)pi.GetValue(this, null);
            if (systm != null)
            {
                systm.Owner = this;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the class:

```
public abstract class Aircraft : OwnerSystem
{
   //a bunch of properties...

    public abstract IntPtr VideoWindow { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pi.DeclaringType` is the type that declares the property, *not* the type of the property. In your case, `DeclaringType` is `Aircraft` or one of its base classes. You should use `pi.PropertyType` instead.